# Apply @JvmStatic and @JvmField automatically to all files in Kotlin

Tags: java, jvm, kotlin

I was wondering if this could be somehow done using compiler parameters or a plugin. I have existing java module that I converted to kotlin, but it has a bunch of static methods/fields. At some point I wanna refactor that, but now my (java) consumer of this library doesn't work unless I manually add missing `@JvmStatic/@JvmField` annotations to companion object fields and methods.
Is there any way to do this automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much work you want to put in to it, you could probably modify the allopen plugin (or write your own):  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html

Comment: Yeah, was thinking the same. But wanna make sure there isn't anything I am missing first.

Comment: Did you find or create such a plugin @K.H. ?